# New RAFT orderer cannot detect that it belongs to an application channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have an initial Hyperledger Fabric network as the following:

[image: initial network]

`org1.example.com` has 2 RAFT nodes. The system channel name is `system-channel` (there is only 1 consortium defined). The application channel name is `channel1` in which the peer from `org1.example.com` runs `chaincode1`. Note that there is no separate orderer organization.

The system channel profile is:

```
    OrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
```

I want to add another organization, `org2.example.com` so that the final network will be:

[image: Final network]

Steps that I took for `system-channel` (I followed https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/raft_configuration.html#reconfiguration):

1. Add `Org2MSP` definition to Orderer Channel Group in `system-channel`
2. Add `Org2MSP` definition to Consortium Channel Group in `system-channel`
3. Add Org2's orderer information (tls certs, etc) to the consenters list i.e. `channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters` in `system-channel`
4. Start Org2's orderer i.e. `orderer0.org2.example.com`
5. Add orderer0.org2.example.com to the list of orderer addresses in `system-channel` i.e. `.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses`

All the above steps work well and `orderer0.org2.example.com` serves `system-channel`

Moving on, the steps that I took for `channel1`:

1. Add `Org2MSP` definition to Orderer Channel Group in `channel1`
2. Add `Org2MSP` definition to Application Channel Group in `channel1`
3. Add `orderer0.org2.example.com` to the list of orderer addresses in `channel1` i.e. `.channel_group.values.OrdererAddresses.value.addresses`
4. Add `orderer0.org2.example.com`'s information (tls certs, etc) to the consenters list i.e. `channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters` in `channel1`

Up to step number 3, everything is OK. Once I completed step 4, I begin to see `channel1 does not exist` errors the following in the newly added orderer `orderer0.org2.example.com`:

```
2019-05-09 09:38:03.360 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 05a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.Cluster grpc.method=Step grpc.peer_address=192.168.224.6:43116 grpc.peer_subject="CN=orderer0.org1.example.com,OU=peer+OU=org1,O=org1.example.com,L=Singapore,ST=Singapore,C=SG" error="channel channel1 doesn't exist" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=711.5µs
```

In the current RAFT leader, there are error messages as well (3 refers to `orderer0.org2.example.com`:

```
2019-05-09 09:38:02.859 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] logSendFailure -> ERRO 0c5 Failed to send StepRequest to 3, because: aborted channel=channel1 node=1
```

It seems that `orderer0.org2.example.com` is not aware that it is supposed to serve `channel1`. I also cannot see `channel1` folder in `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains` in `orderer0.org2.example.com`

As part of my troubleshooting, I tried to persist all the orderers' `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer` folder which contains the chain. shut down `orderer0.org1.example.com` and `orderer0.org2.example.com` and copy the `channel1` folder from `orderer0.org1.example.com` to `orderer0.org2.example.com` and finally start both orderers.

[image: Copy ledger manually]

Now `orderer0.org2.example.com` knows that it needs to serve `channel1` as evidenced in the logs

```
2019-05-10 02:36:04.161 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] apply -> INFO 044 Applied config change to add node 1, current nodes in channel: [1] channel=channel1 node=3
2019-05-10 02:36:04.161 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] apply -> INFO 045 Applied config change to add node 2, current nodes in channel: [1 2] channel=channel1 node=3
2019-05-10 02:36:04.161 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 046 Got block [6], expect block [7], this node was forced to catch up channel=channel1 node=3
2019-05-10 02:36:04.161 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] apply -> INFO 047 Applied config change to add node 3, current nodes in channel: [1 2 3] channel=channel1 node=3
```

Based on above, it is obvious `orderer0.org2.example,com` has no way to receive `channel1`'s block to start serving the channel. For peers, peer can receive the block and issue `peer channel join block_name.block` but orderers can't do that. I am wondering what step am I missing.

To simulate the environment and reproduce the issue, refer to: https://github.com/aldredb/bring-your-own-orderer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is resolved. The issue is that I didn't use the latest config block as the bootstrap block in the new orderer, `orderer0.org2.example.com`. Once I did the aforementioned, `orderer0.org2.example.com` is able to detect `channel1`:

```
2019-05-10 14:06:04.778 UTC [orderer.common.server] replicateDisabledChains -> INFO 072 Successfully replicated 0 chains: []
2019-05-10 14:06:44.680 UTC [orderer.common.server] replicateDisabledChains -> INFO 073 Found 1 inactive chains: [channel1]
2019-05-10 14:06:44.689 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] ReplicateChains -> INFO 074 Will now replicate chains [channel1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the point. I thought fetching latest config of orderer's system channel is not necessary and giving "the very initial" genesis block to the new orderer will be sufficient. We really "must" give the latest config block as "genesis block" of the new orderer!